# How to create Windows app service with dotnet core 3.1 LTS?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

While trying to creating app service with dotnet core 3.1 LTS. There is no option to select to windows in UI.
how to write ARM template to create Windows app service with dotnet core 3.1 LTS?.

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP.NET Core 3.1 LTS is new so **at the time of creation it was not available in windows** but a trick is just to create with 3.0 and once app service created you can publish your 3.1 project to azure and will work well.

> Choose .NET Core 3.0 and Windows and then it will work to run a .NET Core 3.1 app. The availability for the 3.1 SDK, which is only needed for building an 3.1 app can be found here.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/129#issuecomment-595050133) about .NET Core 3.1 Availability on App Service.